# Dynamically loaded content scraping

Tags: java, jsoup, htmlunit

I'm trying to create simple site scraper using Java and jsoup or htmlunit.
I have chosen vk.com as a target site.

My goal is to go through the audio tracks and download them. I started investigation and figured out that there is no URL of tracks in DOM. Track is somehow dynamically downloaded after pressing "play" button.

My question is: how can I capture dynamically loaded file?

Comment: i guess, load in your file system , do whatever you want

Comment: @parladneupane I want to capture it on dynamical loading and do this programmaticaly.

Comment: Have you traced the network tab in your browser ? click on play button and trace request URL and parameters and send that request programatically.

Comment: @FarazIrfan Sure, I can do that, but there is a list of tracks, not one track. How can I do this programmatically for an items list?

Comment: Focus on parameters and see If you can manually inject parameter values via loop and send request ?